# distinct sql rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, distinct

I am trying to join two rows and get the address for only the rows that are contained in the first but I cannot get the values to tally. I have the following query it results in a total of 55,059 records:

```
SELECT 
      AccountID,
      AccountParameter1 
 FROM AccountBaseExtension
```

If I use the following sql I get repeated rows totalling 110,118:

```
SELECT 
      AccountID,
      AccountParameter1,
      AddressParameter1 
 FROM AccountBaseExtension AS A
INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase AS B ON a.AccountID = b.ParentID
```

I am trying to make it distinct so that I am simply retrieving the postcode for the customer address but the query below is resulting in 56,496 records

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT AccountID,
      AccountParameter1,
      AddressParameter1 
 FROM AccountBaseExtension AS A
INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase AS B ON a.AccountID = b.ParentID
```

Anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that in post its SQL server 2008

Comment: Is b.parentID unique within CustomerAddressBase?

Answer (score 0):

Is AccountID part of a primary key or a unique constraint? Possible reasons could be,

- There are duplicate combinations of AccountID,AccountParameter1,AddressParameter1.

  **Test:** Try including the unique column of AccountBaseExtension in your  query. Execute it with and without the distinct keyword.
- AddressParameter1 is not unique in Address table.

  **Test:** Try including the unique column of Address table and query with and without distinct table. For example, there might be records such as:

'

```
AccountID                     AccountParameter1        AddressParameter1     ParentID

10223490                      Cisco                    West Tasman Dr        1
10223490                      Cisco                    West Tasman Dr        2
```

Comment: accountID is a primary key

Comment: Could you try it with AccountId, AccountParameter1, AddressId? Perhaps there are multiple addresses in the Address table with the same AddressParameter..

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that there is `1-->many` relationship between the tables `AccountBaseExtension`  and `CustomerAddressBase`. ie There might be multiple b.parentID for the for the same a.AccountID.For eg Consider the below tables.

**AccountBaseExtension**

```
*---------------*-------------------*
|AccountID      |AccountParameter1  |               count=1
*---------------*-------------------*
|123            |xyzc               |
*---------------*-------------------*
```

**CustomerAddressBase**

```
*---------------*-------------------*
|ParentID       |AddressParameter1  |                count=3
*---------------*-------------------*
|123            |Addr1              |
*---------------*-------------------*
|123            |Addr2              |
*---------------*-------------------*
|123            |Addr2              |
*---------------*-------------------*
```

SELECT 
      AccountID,
      AccountParameter1,
      AddressParameter1 
 FROM AccountBaseExtension AS A
INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase AS B ON a.AccountID = b.ParentID
will result in

```
*---------------*-------------------*------------------*
|AccountID      |AccountParameter1  |AddressParameter1 |     count=3
*---------------*-------------------*------------------*
|123            |xyzc               |Addr1             |
*---------------*-------------------*------------------*
|123            |xyzc               |Addr2             | 
*---------------*-------------------*------------------*
|123            |xyzc               |Addr2             | 
*---------------*-------------------*------------------*
```

And with **distinct** will only produce an output of **2** items.

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference in the result count between queries with and without 'Distinct'.

Comment: @TavoloPerUno updated my answer. try SELECT ParentID       ,AddressParameter1 FROM CustomerAddressBase (with and without DISTINCT) to see if you have repeating rows in CustomerAddressBase

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that there is `1-->many` relationship between the tables `AccountBaseExtension`  and `CustomerAddressBase`. Thus `JOIN` fetches more records than are in the first table. There might be the case that there are multiple `AddressParameter1` for the same AccountID. Thus if you include this column, you get slightly more rows than when it is not included. For tallying results you can go with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      AccountID,
      AccountParameter1 
 FROM AccountBaseExtension AS A
INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase AS B ON a.AccountID = b.ParentID
```

Or you could even try the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, AccountParameter1 FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
          AccountID,
          AccountParameter1,
          AddressParameter1 
     FROM AccountBaseExtension AS A
    INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase AS B 
    ON a.AccountID = b.ParentID
    )A
```

Comment: Edited the second query. No. Of records should be lesser now. But I will never agree that the number of records will go high if you remove the third column from the SELECT clause. If anything it should go lesser. Try again dude.